# Saving a Video in OpenCV (Linux, Python)

Tags: python, linux, opencv

There is an example that works on Windows ([original](https://pythonprogramming.net/loading-video-python-opencv-tutorial/)):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XDIV')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In Linux program provides:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VideoWriter_fourcc'

Help make it work in Linux.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't try but this should work :

```
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
```